# May CKEditor slow down my ASP.NET pages?

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, fckeditor

I have used CKEditor in my ASP.NET pages. But after than, that pages are very slow. Is it possible that it is caused by CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor might be loading a lot of CSS and JavaScript into your page, so it's a possibility.  Have you tried removing it to compare the performance difference?

You could try a tool like [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) to find the bottleneck if you think it's a server-side .NET issue.

Comment: Delay is more than loading CSS and JavaScript, sometimes it take more than one minute to load!